# I am having an error "Error: Cannot find module 'random'" while making a Discord.js bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Please help with the following issue.

I am making a Discord.js bot, but, when I start the bot using "node ." it gives the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'random'
Require stack:
- D:\quote\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1065:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:911:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1125:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\quote\index.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1236:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1257:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'D:\\quote\\index.js' ]
}
```

My code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const random = require('random');

const bot = new Discord.Client();

var stats = {};

bot.on('message' , (message) => {
    if (message.guild.id in stats === false) {
        stats[message.guild.id] = {};
    }

    const guildStats = stats[message.guild.id];
    if (message.author.id in guildStats === false) {
        guildStats[message.author.id] = {
            xp: 0,
            level: 0,
            last_message: 0
        };
    }

    const userStats = guildStats[message.author.id];
    userStats.xp == random.int(15, 25);

    const xpToNextLevel = 5 * Math.pow(userStats.level, 2) - 50 * userStats.level + 100;

    console.log(message.author.username + 'now has' + userStats.xp);
    console.log(xpToNextLevel = ' XP needed for next level.');

const parts = message.content.split(' ');

if(message.content === '!hello') {
    message.reply('hi');
 }
});

bot.login('REMOVED');
```

Comment: Cut n Paste your code and error in question

Comment: Also, Java And Javascript are not related

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to load a module that you haven't installed. Try running `npm i random` in the console in the same directory.